# Using present perfect after the preposition "to"

Tags: present-perfect, prepositional-phrases

I saw the following sentence in a movie:

> He seems to have come out of nowhere

What is rule behind using present perfect after "seems to"

Answer (score 1):

This construction is used when you talk about how a past event appears to you.

> It seems he came out of nowhere.

Becomes-->

> He seems to have come out of nowhere.

And if you want to talk about something current, a general situation, or a habitual act, you use the present simple.

> It seems he is/comes from Berlin.

then you have

> He seems to be/come from Berlin.

When you talk about something ongoing, an action that is happening at the moment, you use the continuous aspect of the present tense

> It seems he is doing something wrong.

So

> He seems to be doing something wrong.